# 2s Complement of a negative zero

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, twos-complement, complement

I have problem: you know the 2s Complement so you can get the negative number of a positive one with the reverse and adding a one. e.g.

```
8 Bit
121 = 0111 1001
 1st= 1000 0110
  +   0000 0001
      ---------
      1000 0111 --> -121
```

So now if we have a -0

a zero looks as 8 bit

```
0000 0000
```

so a minus 0 should look

```
 1111 1111 + 0000 0001
= 10000 0000
```

but that is 512

so I think that I've misunderstood something

Comment: 2s complement is typically for fixed-width numbers. Otherwise, how do you know when to stop inverting bits in the first step? And how would you know which bit is the most significant bit?

Comment: `1111 1111 + 0000 0001` in 8 bit is `0000 0000` the ninth bit is lost because there is no place from it

Comment: @user3580294 I think that the '8 bit' is telling the width you re right otherwis... it also should stop or not because you don't consider the next 00 or not

Comment: @Serpiton so is the 2s Complement of a negativ number the positiv one or... or is it the s2s complement of -0-> -0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1 0000 0000b` is 256, not 512. Truncated to 8 bits, it's 0.

This is because with two's complement, zero is zero. There is no positive or negative zero.

Compare this to one's complement or sign bit, where positive zero and negative zero are different values.

Comment: so the 2's complement of -0 -> 0?

Comment: I mean -0 = 1000 4 bit and 1000 0000 8 bit

Comment: No, `-0` is `0000` 4bit and `0000 0000` 8bit, just like `+0`. Two's complement doesn't differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

To expand my previous comment to the question

`1111 1111 + 0000 0001` in 8 bit is `0000 0000`, the ninth bit is lost because there is no place from it.

And, yes the complement of a negative is a positive

```
-121 = 1000 0111
 1st = 0111 1000
   +   0000 0001
       ---------
       0111 1001 --> 121
```

Think of them as a circle, at one point there is 0, adding 1 at a time you go up to the opposite point (128 in 8 bit) at that point the sign is switched and the absolute value begin to decrease, e.g.: `128 + 1 = -127`, as you continue to add 1 the value go back to 0 and the circle is completed.

So given a number of bit, you only have that much bit, no more, and if you want the value to be signed you really have only x-1 bit for the value, as the most significant bit is used for the sign (0 -> +; 1 -> -)